# Loss in navigability of one's collection with update to iTunes 1.0.0.426

Tags: itunes

I recently updated my OS, which included an update from what had been "iTunes" to Apple Music, version 1.0.0.426. Among other changes, I notice that I can no longer navigate my collection by song via 3 lists on the top half of my screen, listed from left to right, that subdivide one's search from genre to artist to song, or the like. Anyone who has been using substantially iTunes in the past would know what I mean. (I also notice a lack of alternative navigational options, as "searching" for a song yields links to the store, even to options to purchase albums one already has in one's collection, as opposed to links to one's local library.)

Is there a way to recover this navigability in this new interface?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you.  IMHO the functionality has substantially been reduced

Comment: Please don't include the answer in the question, post it as a proper answer below and accept it.

Comment: @nohillside Oh yeah. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the feature I described was called the 3 column browser in iTunes.

According to other users, it has been removed in transitioning to Apple Music. Best we can do to get it back is submit feedback requesting that, here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

As for searching your library, you can recover that by enabling the "Filter" field under View.